# Altering rows in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table1 with 4 columns: `ID, TIME, QUANTITY, STATUS`. Currently there are 50 rows where the fields `ID, TIME`, and `STATUS` are populated, with the `STATUS` column being `NULL` for each row.

I have another table2 that has 2 columns: `ID` and `STATUS`. This table has 150 rows where each `ID` has a corresponding `STATUS` value.

For each `ID` in table1, I want to find the `ID` in table2, find the corresponding `STATUS` value in table2, and insert that `STATUS` value into the proper row based on the corresponding `ID` value in table1.

I feel like it should be fairly easy but all 3 approaches I've tried have failed. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join the tables and update:

```
UPDATE table1
SET
    table1.STATUS = table2.STATUS
FROM
    table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
```

This will only work obviously if the ID values already exist in table1.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The ID values do exist in table1 already. When I run this I get Msg 4104 "The multi-part indentifier "t1.STATUS" could not be bound." Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is. Just triple checked all the names

Comment: I am pretty sure (can't check right now) that the UPDATE clause does not accept a table alias, so the above query should be `UPDATE table1 SET STATUS = t2.STATUS FROM table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID;`

Comment: Thanks @Greenstone, just took the table aliases out.  Aliases aren't needed here anyway.

Comment: That did it. I was hopping around the proper syntax for a while and couldn't quite nail it down. Thanks guys appreciate it!